# Is it possible to update an existing live Facebook app with new permissions?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app which is currently live, but would like to add additional functionality which involves requesting additional permissions (mainly `publish_actions`). The new permissions, due to Facebook policy, need to be reviewed by their team before they can be used live.

Is it possible to use one app for this? Is there a way (and is it acceptable by Facebook) to lead the user down a different flow if they are a tester, rather than a user during the review process?

I've also looked into the possibility of a test app, but I'm not sure if it's possible to flag that the app to review is a test version, which would then be approved on the live app. Facebook's FAQ seems to suggest this is not possible.

Comment: What kind of app are we talking about, a web app? If so, you can tell them in review instructions to test this on a subdomain where you set up your test environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a Facebook page tab app. Because of this, I'm not confident they would follow those sorts of instructions as they would be testing it within Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this as a definite answer, as it's a bit hacky and I have no confirmation that this will work until the review process has been completed. However, you can use the FB API to determine whether the user viewing the app is a specified test account or not by adding conditionals based on the user ID. It will also help if you make the test account an automatic user of the app on user creation.

For example, if you want to include new functionality, check if the user ID is a specific test account ID or not. If it is, display it. If not, display something else.